# Using select case on a left join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have used a left join on two of my tables. Now I want to use case to identify the records from my left table who don't have a match in the right table. Such records exist and have a null value in the 'id_zeus' column of my join, however when I execute the case, it is as these fields don't exist. Where am I going wrong ? I get "Present" in all my column Disturbance. I am using Oracle SQL developer.

```
SELECT 
    CASE DP.ID_PRB
    WHEN  NULL
    THEN 'Absence'
    ELSE 'Present'    END as Disturbance,
FROM 
  FIRE.WSITE WI 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
      DPL.ID_PERT as ID_PRB 
     FROM FIRE.DEPPLAN DPL 
     GROUP BY DPL.ID_PERT
    ) DPL
    ON WI.ID_PERT = DP.ID_PERT
```

Comment: You seem to have an alias typo `DPL` for `DP`.  But there is no reason why every record on the left can't match to something on the right.  It depends on your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `const`?  You don't seem to need it.  The `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are redundant, so use only one of them.  And your alias on the subquery is incorrect.

But your problem is the comparison to `NULL`.  It doesn't even match when doing a comparison as you are doing in `CASE`.  You need to use `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DP.ID_PRB IS NULL THEN 'Absence' ELSE 'Present'
        END) as Disturbance,
FROM FIRE.WSITE WI LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT DPL.ID_PERT as ID_PRB
      FROM FIRE.OSI_DEVIATION_PLANS DP
     ) DP
     ON WI.ID_PERT = DP.ID_PERT;
```

This query would commonly be written as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM FIRE.OSI_DEVIATION_PLANS DP
                              WHERE WI.ID_PERT = DP.ID_PERT
                             )
             THEN 'Absence' ELSE 'Present'
        END) as Disturbance,
FROM FIRE.WSITE WI ;
```

This offers more opportunities for optimization.